# Coworker not giving me tasks despite many follow-ups

Tags: communication, internship, task-management

I'm working as a software engineering intern and finished some project a while ago and My manager promised to give me some new tasks. He did that by asking cc'ing another senior engineer to ask him to assign me the task.

Initially, he set up a meeting and talked me through the first steps, asking me to set up a meeting after finishing the first steps. I finished it the next day and sent him a follow up email right away. However, there are no response, and waited another day to send him another follow up - still no response.

So right now it has been 3 weeks and I sent a total of 6 follows up, also pinged him on skype/teams + cc'ing the manager and still no response so I have been doing my side projects for these weeks.

What should I do in this case?

I figure that he might be busy since it's a fairly large international company and I see that his schedule is full almost every day but I am not sure what I should do. I am already given a return offer few months later should I just keep doing what I'm doing?

Comment: You write that you've sent follow-up emails. But have you actually attempted to schedule another meeting yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Email your manager and be straightforward about the situation.

Say that you’ve completed your assigned work and there doesn’t seem to be more assigned tasks for you.

Indicate that you’ve been working on your side projects, describe in general what they are and ask whether you should continue doing those in the absence of any assigned tasks.

The likelihood is that there’s some project in the pipeline that you’ll be assigned to when it’s at the right stage, but for the moment, you’re benched.

Answer (score 2):

I've been in this situation many times (big company, overseas management and some recent management changes) - I've got one project that I really ought to finish (moving some MS Azure resources from our small regional Azure tenant to the big uber-corporate one where all our other Azure stuff is hosted) - but it requires co-operation from multiple people in multiple timezones and we are very rarely all available at the same time.

So it's possible that this is just bad timing - in the meantime - I'd go out and look for trouble.

That is, investigate things in the company where you may be able to assist and come up with some proposals. Worst case scenario is that you waste a bunch of time and effort - but you've at lease been doing *something* - and if you've completed all the tasks assigned to you, no one can complain that you are slacking off if you've been trying to do other things in the meantime.